# Ember simple-auth AuthenticatedRouteMixin or UnauthenticatedRouteMixin on route depending on condition

Tags: ember.js, mixins, ember-simple-auth

I have a route that should be `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` or `UnauthenticatedRouteMixin` depending on the response coming back from the server.  How do I implement this?

Presently, I have a route with `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` and I am forcing the route to be authenticated and de-authenticated by overriding my beforeModel and implementing the willTransition action as follows.

```
beforeModel() {
  this.set('session.isAuthenticated', true);
  return this._super(...arguments);
}
```

And

```
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(){
      if (Ember.isEmpty(_this.get('session.data.authenticated.token')))
      {
        this.set('session.isAuthenticated', false);
      }
    }
  }
```

However, there are two issues with this.

1. It looks and feels wrong.  There is probably a better way to do
   this.
2. There are some unintended consequences to this.  If not logged in and then try to login, a user needs to refresh the page before it redirects to the appropriate page.  I looked into the simple-auth code and a transitionTo function is not acting as expected.

   ```
   sessionAuthenticated() {
     const attemptedTransition = this.get('session.attemptedTransition');

     if (attemptedTransition) {
       attemptedTransition.retry();
       this.set('session.attemptedTransition', null);
     } else {
       this.transitionTo(Configuration.routeAfterAuthentication);
     }
   }
   ```

`this.transitionTo(Configuration.routeAfterAuthentication);` is the line  that is not transitioning.  I have verified that `Configuration.routeAfterAuthentication` is set correctly.

I may force a reload at the login route or where ever route a user navigates to, but (I think) because of issue 2 above, I am running into infinite redirects.

I would love to do something like the following:

```
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import UnauthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/unauthenticated-route-mixin';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

var mixin;
if (service('session').isAuthenticated){
  mixin = AuthenticatedRouteMixin;
}
else{
  mixin = UnauthenticatedRouteMixin;
}

export default Ember.Route.extend(mixin, { ... })
```

However, I am not getting info from the session.  I am not sure but maybe the specific `Ember.Route` needs to be loaded to get that info.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

## Update

> I may force a reload at the login route or where ever route a user
>   navigates to, but (I think) because of issue 2 above, I am running
>   into infinite redirects.

I figured this part out.  I just set a key/value in the session.  If it is true, reload and remove the key or set it to false, so the reload only happens once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the right way to do this is to do what the mixing is doing manually in your route. Check out the [source code.](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/1.1.0-beta.3/addon/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin.js#L36)

Its not that hard right? The interesting thing is: Why would you want to have the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` when the session is authenticated and the `UnauthenticatedRouteMixin` when the session isn't? Thats basically the same behavior as when you wouldn't include any of the mixing.

Because the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` only changes the behavior when the session is not authenticated, and `UnauthenticatedRouteMixin` only changes the behavior when the route is authenticated.

But something like that in your route is what you asked for:

```
beforeModel(transition) {
  if(...) {
    if (!this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      transition.abort();
      this.set('session.attemptedTransition', transition);
      this.transitionTo(Configuration.authenticationRoute);
      return;
    }
  } else {
    if (this.get('session').get('isAuthenticated')) {
      transition.abort();
      this.transitionTo(Configuration.routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated);
      return;
    }
  }
  return this._super(...arguments);
},
```

Comment: Thanks Lux.  This did not work for me.  I can see the session update as I would expect, but  `this.transitionTo(Configuration.routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated);` does not go to the route specified in `Configuration.routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated`.  I still need to click refresh to see the redirect.

Comment: @user2517182 then something is wrong with your configuration or route. Try to provide a not working twiddle.

Comment: I revamped my code and did something similar to what you have here.  That solved my problem.  Thanks!